Dalgliesh TV episode where the murderer decapitates two women and exchanges their heads
Please help me identify this episode from the Adam Dalgliesh TV series. 
The story: Two women of very different conditions are murdered; one is a prostitute, the other a young successful single professional. They have nothing in common, except for their killer. The killer cuts their heads, then places each body in bed, with the cut head on the pillow. Only the heads have been exchanged!
I have edited the question, since it is very probable (Thank you @walt) that this plot was not an original P.D. James plot but an adaptation of the plot of a novel called "The Switch"/a TV episode called "Doubletake" I still want to find the name of the Dalgliesh episode made of this story. Read on for more details.
Discovering that the heads "don't belong" and connecting the two murders is the first surprise of the investigation. Dalgliesh learns that the "professional" used to do yoga in front of her window (nude maybe?) and suspects that the killer may be someone who had seen her from the building across the street (it's a street with multi-story apartment buildings). 
During this investigation Dalgliesh meets aa woman and becomes attracted to her (the attraction is mutual). Much later, he discovers that this woman's brother (I don't think the brother appears in person) is in jail, and possibly involved in the crimes. This discovery makes him withdraw from the relationship with the woman: she had hidden to him that the brother was doing time in jail ("is searching himself" is what she told Dalgliesh). 
Miskin (a police woman on Dalgliesh's team) appears too. She is trying to be accepted as a member of the team, which means that this story is relatively early in the series. 
This my very first encounter with P.D. James' novels. Later on I read several of her books, but I never found this particular one. I saw this episode in the  late 80's or possibly very early 90's (which means it must have been the series with Roy Marsden). My family had a black and white TV, but on Amazon these movies are in color.
I recently looked up all information about this series on Amazon, and clicked on every book synopsis in the Adam Dalgliesh wikipedia page and even though I recognized several of the books, none of them seemed even remotely similar to this story.
I would like to see this movie again, and perhaps read the book. Besides, having tried for so many years to locate this particular story, and failing, makes it a little mystery of its own. What is it about this story that makes it so hard to find?

Er, are you sure it was Dalgliesh? This is pretty much the plot of the 1985 miniseries Doubletake with Richard Crenna as Det. Frank Janek, based on the book Switch. Similarly, he investigates the murders of a prostitute and a school teacher whose heads were switched, and falls in love with a young photographer (Beverly D'Angelo). See if this clip looks familiar.

Thank you for replying so quickly! No, the clip is not the movie I saw. I am as sure it was Dalgliesh as I am about all the other details. The detective looked like Roy Marsden (I think I said that already), and it was definitely happening in London. The fact that the "teacher" lived in a multi-story house  on a city street mattered (since the murderer was watching her from his window).

Btw, I also searched for "Dalgliesh double take TV mystery", with several variations, and found nothing.

Well, you can briefly see in Doubletake's promo that the teacher does live in an apartment where she walks around in a negligee by her window. So if this isn't the right one, this is either a huge coincidence or grounds for a plagiarism suit. ;) [Since I can't find any other adaptation of this book.]

So, it seems that they "adapted" the plot of Doubletake (or the Switch novel) for the Dalgliesh series. That explains why I can't find it in anything related to PD James.

As an aside, the Dalgliesh Roy Marsden series can be bought on DVD from Amazon. But: 1) only for European zone and 2) there's very little information about the contents. There is one DVD collection where not even the episode titles are listed. I assume that's because they don't sell it in the US.
